# JS DynamoDB to React Prop

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, reactjs, callback, amazon-dynamodb

This will be a simple async issue for some but i've struggled with this for a while.
How can I send the output data object from a DynamoDB document client get as a prop? I'm having scope / context issues which I usually wouldn't.

```
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()

//not how i'm actually doing it but i've tried so many ways. 
render(){
function myJect(stuff){
    var x;
    docClient.get(params, function(err, data){
        x = data.Item.title;
        stuff(x);
    });
  }
function myExt (c){
    this.setState({
        fish: c
    });
}
myJect(MyExt);

return (
  <div>
    <List pug={this.state.fish} />
  </div>
```

Comment: Set a default prop that will hold an initial value, and just call `setState()` in your success callback from DynamoDb setting that properties value to the one you got from Dynamo. But your current example could benefit from some simple cleaning up too...for example what where is the `stuff()` method, and your render method is...unconventional to say the least.

Comment: I see what you're saying but assuming I set a default, the above should work right? I always get undefined returned.

Comment: @jpschroeder I have duplicated the question with something more expressive. My apologies, this was indeed a badly formed post.

Comment: Technically it *might* work, but I still wouldn't endorse having calls to `setState()` in your render method – this is essentially an infinite loop. Consider placing your `docClient.get()` logic in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle event: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount

Comment: Yeah, I was too fresh to react to know better. I now have it working from componentDidMount and used an arrow function in the callback to setState. All groovy now. Thanks for your support.